# Method clearTimeout doesn't work before resetting

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to set a user idle timeout here. Everything seems to work...except the clearTimeout function. Events work, setTimeout works but no matter what I do, as soon as I set it up first time, can't stop it. Method gets called from the onBeforeRendering function of my main controller. No visible error from the debugger. Any help?

```js
   setTimeOut: function () {
    var self = this;

    var timeOut = function userTimeout() { 
     jQuery.sap.log.error("TIMEOUT");
     try {
      if (self.getModel("Global").getProperty("/RecordUnlocked") === true) { 
       self._unlockRecord();
      }
     } catch(e) { 
      jQuery.sap.log.error("TIMEOUT"); 
      
     };
     try {     
      var navHistory = self.getView().getModel("Global").getProperty("/NavHistory"); 
      history.go(navHistory);      
     } catch(e) { 
      jQuery.sap.log.error("TIMEOUT"); 
      
     } 
/*       MessageBox.show(self.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("timeOut"), {
      onClose: function(oAction) {*/
    };

    function reset() {
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        setTimeout(timeOut, 20000); 
    } 
    
    document.onmousemove = reset;
    document.onkeypress = reset;

   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the intention is, or what exactly you're seeing. Your reset function also sets a new timer, no matter how much you reset there's always at least one function finishing after 20s, correct?

Comment: @Jorg Yes, this is the idea.This is testing mode, if works, will change the time-out to 60', It's supposed to be a user inactivity time out. Only problem is that clearTimeout is not clearing the previous one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.clearTimeout` clears the returning value of `window.setTimeout`, not the function you're executing in the timeout itself.

The `timeout` variable you have there is not actually the result of the `setTimeout` function but a function you defined.

Usually, it's something like

```
var myTimeoutFunction = _ => console.log('hi');
var myTimeout = window.setTimeout(myTimeoutFunction, 20000);
window.clearTimeout(myTimeout);
```

As a word of warning, your own function is also called `setTimeout`. Which one is executed in the callback of the mouse- and key events depends on the current context. I guess you're lucky here because the event will run in the window context but it could be confusing if you ever bind the function or something